# how to get a program to compile and display in console

Tags: prolog

I have my own append predicate, and i have made a query for it to append to lists.  I keep getting a singleton variable [X] error and its the X variable in my query. how can I fix this so I can print to console?

```
append1([], List, List).
append1([X | T], List, [X | Y])
:-append1(T, List, Y).

append1([1,2,3], [5,6,7],X).
```

result should be 123567

Comment: The last part append1([1,2,3], [5,6,7],X). should not be a "statement of theory", but a question "a statement to prove", you should use ?- at the beginning.

Comment: thank you, some how I missed that, and the examples I have seen don't show that. it is still giving me the singleton [X] error

Comment: @IvanKuckir: it is not, since there is not dot `.` at the end.

Comment: If I get rid of the ‘.’ At the end I get unexpected end of program error.

Comment: Contrary to what @IvanKuckir wrote, you shoud not be typing `?-` into anything. Save your first three lines to a file, say "append.pl", then run your Prolog implementation, then run `[append].` to load your program, and then enter your query (your fourth line) directly at the `?-` prompt which Prolog gives you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your program is stored in a Prolog file (usually a file with `.pl` extension, here append1.pl), you can change the last line to

```erlang
:- append1([1,2,3],[5,6,7],X), writeln('X'=X).
```

That is, using a directive, you can force the evaluation, then issue a simple output of result. Running from a bash shell:

```
$ swipl append1.pl 
X=[1,2,3,5,6,7]
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.1.10-28-g8a26a53)
...
?-
```

You can then force the interpreter to quit adding another directive `:- halt.` in append1.pl. Running again:

```
$ swipl append1.pl 
X=[1,2,3,5,6,7]
```

*Edit*

As noted in comment, a better solution from the portability viewpoint should use the ISO standard directive [initialization](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(initialization)/1)/1. For instance, in append1.pl, replace the last line with

```erlang
:- initialization((
  append1([1,2,3],[5,6,7],X), writeln('X'=X), halt
)).
```

Comment: Using arbitrary queries as directives is not portable and only works on some Prolog compilers. Worse (although not the case here where you mention having it in the last line), they sometimes assume a single-pass Prolog compiler. Better advice is to use a standard `initialization/1` directive.

Comment: @PauloMoura: yes, I know. I wanted to keep things simple, hoping to help a novice, assuming (s)he's using SWI-Prolog... will complete the answer with your advice.

Comment: @CapelliC I didn't! :) (didn't know, that is)